# C# How to get multiple elements in textfile with in basics for

Tags: c#, for-loop, get, readlines

Here is file data that I want to use and I´m more familiar with python and I can´t find solution what I need here. Thanks for helping.
prices:

Some sold "something 1", price is 20 £
Some sold "something 2", price is 40 £
Some sold "something 3", price is 60 £
Some sold "something 4", price is 80 £
Some sold "something 5", price is 100 £

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CalcPrices
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(
                @"C:\Users\Eggii\Desktop\code\c# katse\GoodsPrices\GoodsPrices\bin\Debug\PriceOfSoldGoods.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] line = lines[i].Split();

                for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line[6]);


                    // Output should be something like:
                    // 20
                    // 40
                    // 60
                    // 80
                    // 100
                    // because I want every 7th element in line 
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try to split by whitespace. It looks like this `string[] line = lines[i].Split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
string[] line = lines[i].Split();
```

for this :

```
string[] line = lines[i].Split(' ');
```

Doing so will split the string with the white space delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split line by whitespace and remove inner loop:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CalcPrices
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(
                @"C:\Users\Eggii\Desktop\code\c# katse\GoodsPrices\GoodsPrices\bin\Debug\PriceOfSoldGoods.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] line = lines[i].Split(' ');
                Console.WriteLine(line[6]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to read all data into one line so you need to change code for this:

```
    ...
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string line = File.ReadAllText(
                @"C:\Users\Eggii\Desktop\code\c# katse\GoodsPrices\GoodsPrices\bin\Debug\PriceOfSoldGoods.txt");

            string[] splitLines = line.Split(' ');
            for (int j = 6; j < line.Length; j += 8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: int j = 6 helped me, so I had to change second for loop , `for (int j = 6; line.Length - 1 > j; j++) { Console.WriteLine(line[j]); }` but in this case no matter is it .split() or .split(' ') because both remove only whitespaces between words?!?!

Comment: @Eggii yes, it will remove split by whitespaces between words in the both cases, [see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1151). So you can take the word that represent your price' value: `20,40...`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Eggii\Desktop\code\c# katse\GoodsPrices\GoodsPrices\bin\Debug\PriceOfSoldGoods.txt");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line.Split(new[] { "price is " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Replace(" £", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So  I add some of my conclusion, maybe it helps someone. Here was problem with title "prices:" top on the text and causes problem because this string was too short for `for-loop` (IndexOutOfRange). So in this case my own corrected code works fine.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CalcPrices
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(
                @"C:\Users\Eggii\Desktop\code\c# katse\GoodsPrices\GoodsPrices\bin\Debug\PriceOfSoldGoods.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] line = lines[i].Split();

                for (int j = 6; j < line.Length-1; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```